# What SPARQL query can return item by its label and description text?

Tags: sparql, wiki, wikidata

How should SPARQL query to looks like to return results by having label and description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please clarify, what is your query, and which dataset are posing it on?

In general, you can use `rdfs:label` to get labels, and you can filter them by language. The example SPARQL query hereinafter works on [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
SELECT * 
WHERE {
   ?x ?y ?z . # any triple 
   ?x rdfs:label ?label . # getting the label of ?x
   FILTER (lang(?label) = "en") # filtering ?label to English labels
}
LIMIT 100
```

For Wikidata, you can use the `SERVICE` and then get item description and label. The following query against [Wikidata endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org/) selects instances of Human, and brings back label and description. By using `SERVICE`, you can get the variables labels and description by appending 'Label' and 'Description' to the query head variables, e.g., for `?x` label, you write `?xLabel`.

```
SELECT ?x ?xLabel ?xDescription # 
WHERE {
  ?x wdt:P31 wd:Q5. # ?x is an instance of Human
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } # English
}
LIMIT 10
```

See [Wikidata query examples](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples) for more wikidata details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
I just mean, for example:
Assume I have a label - "instance of" 
and description - "that class of which this subject is a particular example and member. (Subject typically an individual member with Proper Name label.) Different from P279 (subclass of)"
in english or any other language. 
How I can to detect using SPARQL editor from what property or item they are ?

Comment: Then you have to get all properties that have the label. It's close the first query in the answer above: `seelct ?p {?p rdfs:label "THE_LABEL_YOU_HAVE"@en}`

Comment: Thanks, can you please to give an advice: how I can to get a property of description, when I execute the query above?

Comment: I understand what you talked about. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "get a property of description" -> what? I don't know how descriptions are modelled in Wikidata, but something like `select ?p {?p rdfs:comment "THE_DESCRIPTION_YOU_HAVE"@en}` would work for DBpedia using the `rdfs:comment` property. Once you know the appropriate proeprty for Wikidata, just change it in the query. One comment, this query does *exact matching* of strings. Anything like fuzzy matching is beyond the SPARQL language.